# How to calculate the value of a coin?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages, geometric-progressions

I do not need a specific answer, but a global formula that solves this equation.

There is a coin that costs 100\$ (or 5\$ or \$25 etc.) Each year, it steadily increases by 10% (or 1% or 4% etc.) How much did the coin cost 3 years ago?

X = price

Y = percent of increases

t = time

Thank you for help.

Comment: Honestly, I am very bad at math and I don’t even have a clue where to start searching for this formula. If you know the answer then help, if not then the topic can be closed.

Comment: Try adding some of your work now... like the value$t$ years later, what you understood, or else this can be voted to be closed.

Comment: This formula is needed for my website. I just replaced it with my variables and everything is calculated as needed. But thank you for worrying about my knowledge. The topic can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the coin costs $x_0\$$   at present. And its value increases monotonically by y% every year. Let the cost of the coin t years before was $x_{-t}\$$.
Therefore,

\begin{align}
&\implies x_{-t} \left(\frac{y}{100}+1\right)^t=x_0\\
&\implies x_{-t}= x_0\left(\frac{y}{100}+1\right)^{-t}
\end{align}

Here, $x_{-t}\frac{y}{100}+x_{-t}$ is the increase in value $'t'$ years before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

See the table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
t&-2&-1&0&1&\\
\hline
x_t&100(1+0.1)^{-2}&100(1+0.1)^{-1}&100&100(1+0.1)&\\
\hline
x_t&x_{-2}=x_0(1+0.1)^{-2}&x_{-1}=x_0(1+0.1)^{-1}&x_0&x_1=x_0(1+r)&
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.